# Batch - If not (this) or (that) or (this one) do (that one)?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I'm simply curious as to whether or not it is possible to use any operations on the 'if not' command, namely or. 
The type of thing I want would be along the lines of;

```
if not var==(a1 || a2 || a3 || a4) goto dothis
:dothis
```

Or, the word 'or' being used instead of '||', I hope you know what I'm getting at.
Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?
Thanks in advanced,

Comment: His is if. Mine is if not.

Answer (score 2):

```
for %%a in (a1 a2 a3 a4) if "%var%"=="%%a" goto notdothis
:dothis

:notdothis
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if not "%var%"=="a1" if not "%var%"=="a2" if not "%var%"=="a3" if not "%var%"=="a4" echo it's not them.
```